# Better to solve heteroskedasticity by diffing time steps or by adding variables?

Tags: time-series, self-study, heteroscedasticity

Trying to learn stats on my own and I came across a problem that asked if it better to solve heteroskedasticity by taking the difference between time steps, by adding a variable, or by adding a lag.

Intuitively I thought the order of usefulness would be to add a variable, add a lag, and lastly to take the difference of my data between time steps, but I'm not sure. My thinking was that adding a variable might explain the heteroskedasticity, the lag might also explain the heteroskedasticity, and the time step difference will only serve to increase the heteroskedasticity.

I'm not really sure. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Should probably include all 3 in the title, not just 2

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem with data in mind? Then please include some information, maybe with plots, on that problem!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - No concrete problem in mind. Book said this should be obvious but I'm not sure why

Comment: Maybe you can add some more content from the book. Do they give examples?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - No it was a throwaway line. I forget the exact wording but it was something like "In the case where you have heteroskedasticity, people mistakenly try to solve by taking the difference between time steps, by adding a variable, or by adding a lag. One of these is clearly worse than the other 2..."